# Run an ansible task that is not included in the play, but is part of the role

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that calls the `active_directory` role. Within the main.yml I do not call the `rm_user` task but would like to remove users in the event that I needed to via the CLI. Even tags don't work if the task is not included in the play.

is there a way to run tasks that are not included in the play (but are included in the active_directory `role` directory) via the CLI?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

> Is there a way to run tasks that are not included in the play (but are included in the active_directory role directory) via the CLI?

Yes. There is [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html) module.

You can run

```
# ansible -m include_role -a "name=active_directory tasks_from=file_you_chose.yml"
```